# Efficiently iterate through a data frame to identify tags in over 20 mil different titles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

we have a very large data frame with over 20 mil. instances. In this data frame we have a column named: "titles" which has a length of +/- 10 words. On the other hand we have a list of 7 tags - each of which as a column in the data frame. The challenge is to identify each tag in the title field and set a boolean to True if the tag is in the title.

We have created a loop which works on a small data set, but it uses too much time and RAM on the large, original dataset. We therefore need a more efficient approach to the problem.

Here is our code:

```
tags = ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5', 'Tag6', 'Tag7', 'Tag8', 'Tag9']
titles = total["title"]
checkpoint = 0

for i in tags:
    total[i] = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    checkpoint += 1
    title_list = row["title"].split()
    for i in title_list:
        i = i.upper()
        for x in tags:
            if x in i:
                df.at[index, x] = 1
        else: continue
    if checkpoint % 10000 == 0:
        print(checkpoint)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this dataframe:

```
                      title  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  This is title tag1, tag2   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  This is title tag3, tag2   NaN   NaN   NaN
2        This is title tag3   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Then you can do:

```py
for tag in df.columns[1:]:
    df[tag] = df["title"].str.contains(tag)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                      title   tag1   tag2   tag3
0  This is title tag1, tag2   True   True  False
1  This is title tag3, tag2  False   True   True
2        This is title tag3  False  False   True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - works perfectly. We only have the problem that the Tag comes in different forms. We are looking for upper case with the columns but in the title it is sometimes lower case or with a dollar sign before it. Can we test various versions of the tag?